# Рекурсивно обойти папки и добавить в массив. Почему код работает на Андроид 7, но не на 10?

Tags: java, рекурсия

```
List<String> localList(File rootDir) { // /storage/emulated/0

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<File> fileTree = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Collections.addAll(fileTree, Objects.requireNonNull(rootDir.listFiles())); // LocalC.java:18 

    while (!fileTree.isEmpty()) {
        File currentFile = fileTree.remove();
        if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            Collections.addAll(fileTree, Objects.requireNonNull(currentFile.listFiles()));
            result.add(currentFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(""+rootDir, ""));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

> 

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RService.HandlerThread
>     Process: com.example.projectq, PID: 18490
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
>         at com.example.projectq.LocalC.localCList(LocalC.java:18)
```

Comment: Забыл запросить разрешения на доступ к карте?

Comment: @Qwertiy вечная проблема, постоянно забываю. Но не в этот раз)

Comment: С 9 или 10 андроида без явного запроса разрешения юзера на доступ к файловой системе (даже к конретной папке/файлу) не получится ничего сделать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб т.е. в манифесте и настройках для приложения дать разрешение не достаточно, нужно именно диалоговое окно запрашивать??

Comment: Да, всё верно. Где-то в доке это написано)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну и жесть, попробую. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения достаточно добавить в Манифест:

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
```